# Gutenberg PluginDocumentSettingPanel retrieve post name

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to add language switch links in my WordPress gutenberg so that I can switch to the corresponding language edit page easily.

I follow this step: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/slotfills/plugin-document-setting-panel/.

The "Language Switcher" section appears successfully, but I don't know how I can add the edit links.

My ideas are:

1. To get the edit link, we need to know the post_id.
2. The post names are consistent among the whole websites, say, a post is in language1.example.com/post1, then it has language2.example.com/post1, language3.example.com/post1, and so on...
3. So, I need to get the post name first, then get the post id for the other languages, and then save them into a list of links.

However, I am stuck with step 3, I don't know how to get the post name properly...

Below is my code:

```
import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins';
import { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } from '@wordpress/edit-post';

const { select } = wp.data;
const title = select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute( 'title' );

const languageSwitcher = () => (
    <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
        name="custom-panel"
        title="Language Switcher"
        className="custom-panel"
    >
        <a>English {title}</a>
        <a>简体中文</a>
        <a>繁體中文</a>
    </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
);
 
registerPlugin( 'language-switcher', {
    render: languageSwitcher,
    icon: 'translation',
} );
```

Now, select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute( 'title' ) returns `undefined`...

I really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding wp-data to your wp_enqueue_script.
Ex:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'your-doc',
    plugins_url( 'build/yourDoc.js', __DIR__ ),
    [ 'wp-i18n', 'wp-edit-post', 'wp-element', 'wp-data' ],
    '0.0.1',
    true
);
```